# JBoss 4.2 can't be started (controlled) from Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, batch-file, jboss

I have this (requested) setup:
Windows 7 64 bit, JBoss 4.2, Eclipse Luna.
JBossAS Tools (3.0.3.Beta1-v20150220-1545-B124, by RedHat) added through Install New Extension.

I can start without problems JBoss externaly - in it's directory with BAT file.
But I can't start it through Eclipse - it stays in some "in between state" [Starting, Synchronized] ,so I can't start it , stop it ,restart it, publish, clean or even connect with JRebel but that is whole another story. It says in the end that it is started but it isn't.

What puzzles me is that exxternally it starts OK and works OK. Also on other workstation it can be started/controlled from Eclipse without any problems.

My question is what should I do about it?

I am totally confused with this error "Failed to register driver for: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver; - nested throwable:" as it works OK when started externally, so I guess configuration is OK

None of similar questions helped me:
[Cannot start JBoss from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451102/cannot-start-jboss-from-eclipse)

I checked this too, but I don't have same setting as showed in one of replies:
[Starting JBoss from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298312/starting-jboss-from-eclipse)

Checked this as well:
[Tomcat can be started using startup.bat but not from eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21760244/tomcat-can-be-started-using-startup-bat-but-not-from-eclipse)

and this:
[JBoss fails to start from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184340/jboss-fails-to-start-from-eclipse)

In my case console output from eclipse is:

```
16:25:24,597 INFO  [Server] Starting JBoss (MX MicroKernel)...
16:25:24,597 INFO  [Server] Release ID: JBoss [Trinity] 4.2.2.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_2_GA date=200710221139)
16:25:24,598 INFO  [Server] Home Dir: C:\bin\jboss
16:25:24,598 INFO  [Server] Home URL: file:/C:/bin/jboss/
16:25:24,598 INFO  [Server] Patch URL: null
16:25:24,598 INFO  [Server] Server Name: psg
16:25:24,598 INFO  [Server] Server Home Dir: C:\bin\jboss\server\psg
16:25:24,598 INFO  [Server] Server Home URL: file:/C:/bin/jboss/server/psg/
16:25:24,599 INFO  [Server] Server Log Dir: C:\bin\jboss\server\psg\log
16:25:24,599 INFO  [Server] Server Temp Dir: C:\bin\jboss\server\psg\tmp
16:25:24,599 INFO  [Server] Root Deployment Filename: jboss-service.xml
16:25:24,777 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java version: 1.6.0_29,Sun Microsystems Inc.
16:25:24,777 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 20.4-b02,Sun Microsystems Inc.
16:25:24,777 INFO  [ServerInfo] OS-System: Windows 7 6.1,x86
16:25:25,033 INFO  [Server] Core system initialized
16:25:26,387 INFO  [WebService] Using RMI server codebase: http://localhost:8086/
16:25:26,389 INFO  [Log4jService$URLWatchTimerTask] Configuring from URL: resource:jboss-log4j.xml
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 302 and column 11
log4j:WARN The content of element type "root" must match "(param*,(priority|level)?,appender-ref*)".
16:25:26,595 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] JBossTS Transaction Service (JTA version) - JBoss Inc.
16:25:26,595 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Setting up property manager MBean and JMX layer
16:25:26,679 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Starting recovery manager
16:25:26,749 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Recovery manager started
16:25:26,749 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Binding TransactionManager JNDI Reference
16:25:27,942 INFO  [EJB3Deployer] Starting java:comp multiplexer
16:25:28,198 INFO  [STDOUT] no object for null
16:25:28,199 INFO  [STDOUT] no object for null
16:25:28,207 INFO  [STDOUT] no object for null
16:25:28,215 INFO  [STDOUT] no object for {urn:jboss:bean-deployer}supplyType
16:25:28,218 INFO  [STDOUT] no object for {urn:jboss:bean-deployer}dependsType
16:25:29,056 INFO  [NativeServerConfig] JBoss Web Services - Native
16:25:29,056 INFO  [NativeServerConfig] jbossws-native-2.0.1.SP2 (build=200710210837)
16:25:29,364 INFO  [SnmpAgentService] SNMP agent going active
16:25:29,429 INFO  [TreeCache] No transaction manager lookup class has been defined. Transactions cannot be used

16:25:30,670 WARN  [JBossManagedConnectionPool] Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null
org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Failed to register driver for: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver; - nested throwable: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver))
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:179)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:577)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:262)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool$BasePool.getConnection(JBossManagedConnectionPool.java:500)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.getManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:341)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManager.java:315)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:396)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2$ConnectionManagerProxy.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:842)
....... ommited ....
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Failed to register driver for: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver; - nested throwable: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getDriver(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:287)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:170)
    ... 124 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver
    at org.jboss.mx.loading.LoadMgr3.beginLoadTask(LoadMgr3.java:212)
    at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClassImpl(RepositoryClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClass(RepositoryClassLoader.java:415)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getDriver(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:272)
    ... 125 more
16:25:30,672 WARN  [ServiceController] Problem starting service jboss.cache:service=TomcatClusteringCache
org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Failed to register driver for: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver; - nested throwable: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver)); - nested throwable: (org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Failed to register driver for: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver; - nested throwable: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver)))
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:94)
    at org.jboss.cache.loader.JDBCCacheLoader$ManagedConnectionFactory.getConnection(JDBCCacheLoader.java:1601)
    at org.jboss.cache.loader.JDBCCacheLoader.start(JDBCCacheLoader.java:753)
    at org.jboss.cache.loader.AsyncCacheLoader.start(AsyncCacheLoader.java:305)
    at org.jboss.cache.loader.CacheLoaderManager.startCacheLoader(CacheLoaderManager.java:353)
    at org.jboss.cache.TreeCache.startService(TreeCache.java:1535)
....... ommited ....
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Failed to register driver for: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver; - nested throwable: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver))
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:179)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:577)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:262)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool$BasePool.getConnection(JBossManagedConnectionPool.java:500)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.getManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:341)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManager.java:315)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:396)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2$ConnectionManagerProxy.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:842)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:88)
    ... 116 more
Caused by: org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Failed to register driver for: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver; - nested throwable: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getDriver(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:287)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:170)
    ... 124 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver
    at org.jboss.mx.loading.LoadMgr3.beginLoadTask(LoadMgr3.java:212)
    at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClassImpl(RepositoryClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClass(RepositoryClassLoader.java:415)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getDriver(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:272)
    ... 125 more
16:25:31,039 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=DefaultDS' to JNDI name 'java:DefaultDS'
16:25:31,130 INFO  [A] Bound to JNDI name: queue/A
16:25:31,131 INFO  [B] Bound to JNDI name: queue/B
16:25:31,132 INFO  [C] Bound to JNDI name: queue/C
16:25:31,132 INFO  [D] Bound to JNDI name: queue/D
16:25:31,133 INFO  [ex] Bound to JNDI name: queue/ex
16:25:31,143 INFO  [testTopic] Bound to JNDI name: topic/testTopic
16:25:31,143 INFO  [securedTopic] Bound to JNDI name: topic/securedTopic
16:25:31,144 INFO  [testDurableTopic] Bound to JNDI name: topic/testDurableTopic
16:25:31,146 INFO  [testQueue] Bound to JNDI name: queue/testQueue
16:25:31,155 INFO  [UILServerILService] JBossMQ UIL service available at : localhost/127.0.0.1:8093
16:25:31,172 INFO  [DLQ] Bound to JNDI name: queue/DLQ
16:25:31,208 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=ConnectionFactoryBinding,name=JmsXA' to JNDI name 'java:JmsXA'
16:25:31,213 ERROR [URLDeploymentScanner] Incomplete Deployment listing:

--- Packages waiting for a deployer ---
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@8aafac5d { url=file:/C:/bin/jboss/server/psg/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/ROOT.war/ }
  deployer: null
  status: Starting
  state: INIT_WAITING_DEPLOYER
  watch: file:/C:/bin/jboss/server/psg/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/ROOT.war/
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1426605929863
  lastModified: 1426584051328
  mbeans:

org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@5cf4ae87 { url=file:/C:/bin/jboss/server/psg/deploy/httpha-invoker.sar/invoker.war/ }
  deployer: null
  status: Starting
  state: INIT_WAITING_DEPLOYER
  watch: file:/C:/bin/jboss/server/psg/deploy/httpha-invoker.sar/invoker.war/
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1426605929863
  lastModified: 1426584051202
  mbeans:

org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@e8e6151b { url=file:/C:/bin/jboss/server/psg/deploy/jbossws.sar/jbossws-context.war/ }
  deployer: null
  status: Starting
  state: INIT_WAITING_DEPLOYER
  watch: file:/C:/bin/jboss/server/psg/deploy/jbossws.sar/jbossws-context.war/
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1426605929863
  lastModified: 1426584051349
  mbeans:

org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@8aea0a50 { url=file:/C:/bin/jboss/server/psg/deploy/jms/jbossmq-httpil.sar/jbossmq-httpil.war/ }
  deployer: null
  status: Starting
  state: INIT_WAITING_DEPLOYER
  watch: file:/C:/bin/jboss/server/psg/deploy/jms/jbossmq-httpil.sar/jbossmq-httpil.war/
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1426605929863
  lastModified: 1426584051387
  mbeans:

org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@435b5b3f { url=file:/C:/bin/jboss/server/psg/deploy/juddi-service.sar/juddi.war/ }
  deployer: null
  status: Starting
  state: INIT_WAITING_DEPLOYER
  watch: file:/C:/bin/jboss/server/psg/deploy/juddi-service.sar/juddi.war/
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1426605929863
  lastModified: 1426584051448
  mbeans:

org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@68b7867b { url=file:/C:/bin/jboss/server/psg/deploy/management/console-mgr.sar/web-console.war/ }
  deployer: null
  status: Starting
  state: INIT_WAITING_DEPLOYER
  watch: file:/C:/bin/jboss/server/psg/deploy/management/console-mgr.sar/web-console.war/
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1426605929863
  lastModified: 1426584051642
  mbeans:

org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@f99a4b2b { url=file:/C:/bin/jboss/server/psg/deploy/jmx-console.war/ }
  deployer: null
  status: null
  state: INIT_WAITING_DEPLOYER
  watch: file:/C:/bin/jboss/server/psg/deploy/jmx-console.war/
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1426605931210
  lastModified: 1426584051413
  mbeans:

org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@fa9f8de6 { url=file:/C:/bin/jboss/server/psg/deploy/mc_dev1_4170.war/ }
  deployer: null
  status: null
  state: INIT_WAITING_DEPLOYER
  watch: file:/C:/bin/jboss/server/psg/deploy/mc_dev1_4170.war/
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1426605931211
  lastModified: 1426588326490
  mbeans:

--- Incompletely deployed packages ---
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@f99a4b2b { url=file:/C:/bin/jboss/server/psg/deploy/jmx-console.war/ }
  deployer: null
  status: null
  state: INIT_WAITING_DEPLOYER
  watch: file:/C:/bin/jboss/server/psg/deploy/jmx-console.war/
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1426605931210
  lastModified: 1426584051413
  mbeans:

org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@fa9f8de6 { url=file:/C:/bin/jboss/server/psg/deploy/mc_dev1_4170.war/ }
  deployer: null
  status: null
  state: INIT_WAITING_DEPLOYER
  watch: file:/C:/bin/jboss/server/psg/deploy/mc_dev1_4170.war/
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1426605931211
  lastModified: 1426588326490
  mbeans:

--- MBeans waiting for other MBeans ---
ObjectName: jboss.cache:service=TomcatClusteringCache
  State: FAILED
  Reason: org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Failed to register driver for: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver; - nested throwable: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver)); - nested throwable: (org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Failed to register driver for: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver; - nested throwable: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver)))
  I Depend On:
    jboss:service=Naming
    jboss:service=TransactionManager
    jboss.aop:service=AspectDeployer
    jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=DB2DS
  Depends On Me:
    jboss.web:service=WebServer

--- MBEANS THAT ARE THE ROOT CAUSE OF THE PROBLEM ---
ObjectName: jboss.cache:service=TomcatClusteringCache
  State: FAILED
  Reason: org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Failed to register driver for: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver; - nested throwable: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver)); - nested throwable: (org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Failed to register driver for: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver; - nested throwable: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver)))
  I Depend On:
    jboss:service=Naming
    jboss:service=TransactionManager
    jboss.aop:service=AspectDeployer
    jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=DB2DS
  Depends On Me:
    jboss.web:service=WebServer


16:25:31,237 INFO  [Server] JBoss (MX MicroKernel) [4.2.2.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_2_GA date=200710221139)] Started in 6s:637ms
```

Comment: On this case you start the psg server directory of your jboss, when you use your bat file do you also start the psg instance? Perhaps you can take a look to your boot.log file to check differences between starting from bat or starting from eclipse (JVM used, JVM parameters ...)

Comment: @alphamikevictor Yes, when I use my bat file I use exclusively psg configuration - instance.

Comment: I suggest you to boot your jboss with .bat file, save the boot.log file and then boot jboss with eclipse, then compare with diff or any other tools possible differences. Perhaps in the run.conf.bat something is introduced which is not by eclipse (classpath, JAVA_OPTS parameters, parameters for Jboss ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I finally solved this.
Eclipse Luna, JBoss, 4.20GA, Windows 7 Pro 64.

1. I downloaded and installed ibm_data_server_client_win64_V97. This created directory C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\java with several files of which those ones were necessary for this to work: **db2java.zip** (not sure about this one), **db2jcc.jar** (this is a MUST), **db2jcc_license_cu.jar** (some say this is not necessary, some other say this is a must). Those libraries I could (probably) get with direct download from IBM's section "DB2 JDBC Driver Versions and Downloads", but I needed this client for some other reason, and it seems libraries are same anyway.
2. Then in Eclipse I added those jar's and zip to my project with: Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries Tab -> Add external jars: then I navigated to  "C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\java\"and selected all of them.
3. After that, I cleaned and rebuild project, started JBoss from Eclipse and that's it. It even gave (to some extent) possibility for hot deployment.